# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)

Tags: java, android, retrofit

When I set The data it says

```
String enrloment = studentData.get(position).getEnrollments()
                              .get(position).getCourse().getTitle();
```

this line

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1         
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
```

my app crashed.

I am  using retrofit library for get data

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StudentViewholde holder, int position) {
    holder.idTv.setText(studentData.get(position).getID().toString());
    holder.nameTv.setText(studentData.get(position).getFirstMidName());
    String enrloment = studentData.get(position).getEnrollments().get(position).getCourse().getTitle();
    holder.enrolmentId.setText(enrloment);
}
```

Comment: `getEnrollments().get(position)` better check that `position` is less than the length of the `List`

Comment: `position` in `onBindViewHolder` is for studentData, which is your source of recyclerview, not for getEnrollments. If you want to display something from subdata, you should check size of that list for single item, or use next recyclerview to display this as list inside first recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1 at
> java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1 at:

This specifies that the size of the data in the list is 1 i.e. only one element is present in the arraylist whereas you are trying to call the 2nd index element of the list (3rd element).

Since, the list contains only 1 element, the app is getting crashed.

Check:

- Whether the response has more than 1 elements or not.

> Problem: The response returned has only 1 element.

Comment: actually, he's trying to call the third element. Arrays and lists indexes are 0-based

Comment: Hit the api on Postman and paste your response here, will explain.

Comment: i am using json data which is made by dotnet

Answer (score 0):

actually i don't understand. Please See my Pojo class and adapter Class

it Student information POJO Class

https://github.com/amintushar2/Demo-Intern/blob/master/StudentInformation.class

it Enrollment POJO Class

https://github.com/amintushar2/Demo-Intern/blob/master/Enrollment.class

adapter Class
https://github.com/amintushar2/Demo-Intern/blob/master/StudentAdapter.Class